# A limit related to the $\zeta(3)$ and the fractional part

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I need some clues, hints for proving that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\frac{\displaystyle \left\{\frac{n}{\sqrt{1}}\right\}+ \left\{\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}+ \left\{\frac{n}{\sqrt{3}}\right\}+\cdots  +\left\{\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}}\right\}}{\displaystyle \left\{\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{1}}\right\}+ \left\{\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right\}+ \left\{\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\right\}+\cdots  +\left\{\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^3}}\right\}}=\frac{\pi^2-12}{6\zeta(3)-9}$$

My first idea was to use [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), but this doesn't seem an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be easier to write it as $$\frac{2-\zeta(2)}{3/2-\zeta(3)}$$

The numerator is $n^2$ times a Riemann sum for $$\int_{0}^1 \left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right\}dx$$

The denominator is $n^3$ times a Riemann sum for:

$$\int_0^1  \left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\right\}dx$$

Since $\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx = 2$ and $\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}dx = 3/2$ that seems like the right place to start, since $\int_{0}^1 \{f(x)\}dx$ is $\int_0^1\ f(x) dx$ adjusted subtracting a value that can be expressed as a sum.

Specifically,

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 \left\lfloor \frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{x}}\right\rfloor dx&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{(n+1)^k}}^{\frac{1}{n^k}} ndx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{1}{n^k}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^k}\right) = \zeta(k)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh, yeahhh. (+1)